# MySQL select using an array

Tags: php

I edit my code working good but still one problem ... the data that selected from my database and displayed in my suggestion input ( only one row and last ID ) !!! How can I do it to display all data rows from my database ????

```
<?php
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

if (!$q) return;

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "private_message_system";

//make connection
$server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


    $items = array($row["user_name"] => $row["user_email"]);    

}

$result = array();

foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {

    array_push($result, array(
        "name" => $key,
        "to" => $value
    ));
}
}

echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: So you want these to come from a DB?

Comment: I don't see any MySQL here. It looks like you are turning an array into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

See below for a basic implementation of connecting to MySQL and searching for your `$q`, I've left a few comments for you to make it clearer what's going on!

```
<?php

// Get the query term from the url
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);

// Do nothing if it's empty or not set
if (empty($q)) return;

// Result array which we are going to get from MySQL
$result= array();

// Make a SQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "password") or die(mysql_error());

// Try to connect to your DATABASE (change the name) or throw an error
mysql_select_db("DATABASE") or die(mysql_error());

// Get data from the "email" table 
// Where the name field is LIKE the search term
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM email WHERE name LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($q)."%'") 
or die(mysql_error());  //throw an error if something went wrong

//Read all the results ($row) in a loop and put them in the result array
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $result[] = array('name' => $row['name'], 'to' => $row['to']);
} 

// Output the array as JSON
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

*For the more PHP experienced I am aware you can get an array from MySQL but have left it like this to make it clearer.*

---

Enable error reporting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: that's autocomplete code take a result suggestion from above code with file name emails.php in the suggestion result you will see the name and emails of users (Peter Pan"=>"peter@pan.de and "Molly"=>"molly@yahoo.com" ... etc ) i need to remove the names and email's and selected from my database

Comment: @ Saeed Aknan. what are you trying to say? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ roel. the above code not working nothing displayed not helpful ... understand ???

Comment: You need to tell us an ERROR or the output or something... "not working" "not helpful" is a pretty poor response to someone trying to help you

Comment: Have you even made the tables in your DATABASE? Do you even have a database?

Comment: I have a table in my database and every thing working good when i edit the code as you write no result showing in my input suggestion that meaning the code you write not select data from my database only blank without ERROR code .... I can send to you the script by email and you will try

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? Can you please add the code above to enable error reporting and try again.

Answer (score 0):

As I know mysql doesn't have a array type like postgres so you have to fetch it one by one:

```
// here is where you get your to connection to the database
$conn = mysql_connect("your IP", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

// here you have to do the select to retrieve data from the table.
$query = "SELECT `name`, `to` from mytable";

// now you got all the records but you still need to iterate over this result
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$array = array();

  // retrieve a record and append it to the array
 while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
   $array[] = $record;

 endwhile;

// please close the door.... 
 mysql_close($conn);
  echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: See the comment on mine, *sigh*